# How to set an AnsiString param in an event handler?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, eventhandler

I'm preparing some parts of a Delphi 2007 project to easily migrate to Delphi XE7.

I've switched a parameter's type of an event handler from `string` to `AnsiString` (This particular event handler must work with `AnsiString`).

**Runtime package:**

```
  TMyAnsiStringFunction = function(const APar : AnsiString) : AnsiString of object;
  TMyTestComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyAnsiStringFunction : TMyAnsiStringFunction;
  published
    property MyAnsiStringFunction : TMyAnsiStringFunction read FMyAnsiStringFunction write FMyAnsiStringFunction;
  end;
```

**Designtime package:**

```
procedure Register;
begin   
  RegisterComponents('MyComponents', [TMyTestComponent]);
end;
```

When I doubleclick on the `MyAnsiStringFunction` from the *Object Inspector*, it automatically creates a function with a `string` param and a `string` resulting type instead of `AnsiString`:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MyTestComponent1: TMyTestComponent;
    function MyTestComponent1MyAnsiStringFunction(const APar: string): string;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

If I manually change the param and resulting type from `string` to `AnsiString`, then I get the following error while saving changes:

[image]

> The MyTestComponent1MyAnsiStringFunction method referenced by
>   MyTestComponent1.MyAnsiStringFunction has an incompatible parameter
>   list. Remove the reference?

Why is this happening and is there a way to force the `AnsiString` type?

Comment: Are you doing the double click in D2007 or in XE7?

Comment: I guess you can't force a non-distinct type, they are the same. Why the IDE uses "string" and not "AnsiString" could be some implementation detail.

Comment: If easy migration indeed matters, I'd use a new type MyAnsiString = type AnsiString.

Comment: `string` is `AnsiString` in D2007, so it makes sense for a pre-D2009 IDE to substitute `string` in for `AnsiString`, they are the same type.  But `string` is `UnicodeString` in D2009+, so a post-D2007 IDE should not be doing that substitution for `AnsiString`, only for `UnicodeString`.

Comment: Presumably the right solution is to use string

Comment: `String` for textual data, `TBytes` or `TStream` for binary data. There is little use for `AnsiString` in modern D2009+ code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't agree with your claim that there is little use of `AnsiString` in modern Delphi code. I myself have a modrn Delphi application where in most cases I purposely use `AnsiString` in order to decrease memory usage since none of those strings require any Unicode characters. So by using `AnsiString` instead of `String` I reduce memory consumption of my application for about 350 MB. Granted on PC's with 8 or 16 GB of RAM this seems insignificant but I plan on eventually porting my application to mobile devices where RAM space  is much more scarce

Comment: @SilverWarior The *majority* of users don't need `AnsiString` over `UnicodeString`. In your particular case, `UTF8String` would usually make more sense than `AnsiString`, since handling of `AnsiString` codepages doesn't port well to non-Windows platforms. Stick with Unicode for all text, just using UTF-8 instead of UTF-16 if memory usage is an issue. But I doubt it, since Android and iOS use UTF-16 strings natively, as does FMX. How you process data outside of APIs is up to you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'm doing the double click in D2007

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Thank you! It works, doing this way IDE automatically creates event handler using `MyAnsiString` type

Comment: @Fabrizio you're welcome. I converted the comment to an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `string` is an alias for `AnsiString`, as far as D2007 is concerned, there is no functional difference and the IDE feels free to substitute the more commonly used `string` in place of the actual type used. This can be thought of as a short sight but the experiment you perform is conclusive regarding whether the `AnsiString` type can be forced, this is not about your code but the IDE's.

Nothing needs to be done if only the package would be migrated. Because when compiled under XE7, the IDE cannot substitute `string` with `AnsiString` as the former is an alias for `UnicodeString` since D2009.

However if consumers of the package are also to be migrated, you need to use a distinct type. Like

```
type
  MyAnsiString = type AnsiString;
```

Note that you won't be able to pass one of the types as a var parameter for the other ([link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Data_Types,_Variables,_and_Constants_Index_(Delphi))) but this will probably be of no consequence when used as a parameter for an event handler.